# Interpolate points along a 3d line

Tags: python, r, line

Although I outline the problem in *R*, answers in *R* and *Python* are welcome.

Suppose we have a set of points in x,y,z that define a discrete path (or set of connected line segments) over a vector of time t. These paths are not monotonic in z.

```
path <- data.frame(x = c(245, 233, 270, 400, 380),
                   y = c(245, 270, 138, 225, 300),
                   z = c(0, 1.2, 5, 3, 9),
                   t = 1:5)


plot3D::scatter3D(path$x, path$y, path$z, type = "b", bty = "g", 
                  phi = 0, col = "red", pch = 20, ticktype = "detailed")
```

[image]

## How can I interpolate along the path at some arbitrary resolution in z?

For example, say I wanted to retain a resolution in z of 1 unit. The points along z are 0, 1.2, 5, 3, 9. Therefore, one possible solution that satisfies this constraint is to interpolate at 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 in the z direction, yielding the blue points in the figure below (labels indicate z location):

[image]

Ultimately, I would like the coordinates of the blue dots. We can brute force the solution by sequentially solving for the equation of the line in 3d for each pair of points z, and then interpolating along each line segment. However, I want to make sure I'm not missing some existing implementation or clever hack.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/interp1 ?

Comment: Thanks @Dan! I've seen this, but can't see how it might be generalized to 3d.

Comment: The easiest probable solution is `funX<-approxfun(path$z, path$x)` and likewise for y, then calling `funX(your_z_vals)` and likewise for y.

Comment: @RichPauloo if you want linear interpolation, pretty sure you can just do linear interpolation of x-z and linear interpolation of y-z separately and you'll get the result you're after. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `purrr::map` just to tie it all together into a single tibble, but you could easily do them independently. The only problem is if your `x` or `y` is NOT monotonic over `z`. Then you'll need to do a fourth variable indicating row order, and it gets even more complicated from there.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(plotly)

path3d <- data.frame(
  x = c(245, 233, 270, 400, 380),
  y = c(245, 270, 138, 225, 300),
  z = c(0, 1.2, 3, 5, 9)
  )

path3d_interp <- list(
  x = approxfun(path3d$z, path3d$x),
  y = approxfun(path3d$z, path3d$y)
) %>% 
  map(~.x(1:8)) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(z = 1:8)
```

> ```
>       x     y     z
>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
> 1  235   266.     1
> 2  249.  211.     2
> 3  270   138      3
> 4  335   182.     4
> 5  400   225      5
> 6  395   244.     6
> 7  390   262.     7
> 8  385   281.     8
> ```

```
plot_ly(path3d) %>% 
  add_paths(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z) %>% 
  add_markers(
    x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
    data = path3d_interp
    )
```

[image]

---

## Updated for non-monotonic in `z`:

I can't think of an especially elegant way to predict `x` and `y` exactly if there isn't exactly 1 solution for each desired `z`. The general outline I'd suggest is creating a `funX`, `funY`, and `funZ` of each variable, as predicted by your time `t`. Then using a very high-resolution vector of new `t` values and subsetting it for `funZ(new_t_values)`. You'll never get exactly to the values you're looking for, but you can approximate them to the desired arbitrary precision:

```
path3d <- data.frame(
  x = c(245, 233, 270, 400, 380),
  y = c(245, 270, 138, 225, 300),
  z = c(0, 1.2, 5, 3, 9),
  t = 1:5
  )
```

Just to get a good visual of what's going on here with respect to `t`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(path3d) + 
  geom_path(aes(t, x), color = "blue") +
  geom_path(aes(t, y), color = "red") +
  geom_path(aes(t, z*50), color = "orange") +
  labs(y = "x, y, z*50")
```

[image]

This is looping over each column of `path3d` (`x`, `y`, `z`, and `t`) and creating a linear interpolation function for each variable against `t` as a predictor.

```
path3d_interp_funs <- 
  map(path3d, ~approxfun(path3d$t, .x))
```

---

#### Inspect the full range of `t`:

Now we can make a high resolution vector across the entire range of `t`, here 1 million elements. You can increase this as much as your precision requires and your memory allows.

```
new_t_values <- seq(min(path3d$t), max(path3d$t), length.out = 1e6)
```

> ```
>  1.000000 1.000004 1.000008 1.000012 1.000016 1.000020 ...
> ```

#### Generate the full path of `z`:

Now we see what the `z` values are for each possible `t` in the range.

```
z_candidates <- path3d_interp_funs$z(new_t_values)
```

> ```
> 0.000000e+00 4.800005e-06 9.600010e-06 1.440001e-05 1.920002e-05 2.400002e-05 ...
> ```

#### Test where approximate-`z` is closest to your desired `z`:

So now we take each desired value of `z` (`1:8`), and ask which element of the `z_candidates` vector has the smallest absolute deviation from it. This returns indices we can use to subset `new_t_values`.

```
t_indices <- map_dbl(1:8, ~which.min(abs(z_candidates-.x)))
```

> ```
> 208334 302632 750000 434211 500001 875000 916667 958333
> ```

A sanity check: do those chosen `t` values result in the `z`s you want?

```
path3d_interp_funs$z(new_t_values[t_indices])
```

> ```
> 0.9999994 1.9999958 3.0000020 3.9999986 4.9999960 5.9999970 7.0000060 7.9999910
> ```

---

#### Generate your desired data:

So let's loop over each of those approximating functions, evaluating each one at our new chosen values of `t`:

```
path3d_interp <- 
  path3d_interp_funs %>%
  map(~.x(new_t_values[t_indices])) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 x 4
>       x     y     z     t
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1  235.  266. 1.000  1.83
> 2  241.  242. 2.00   2.21
> 3  400.  225. 3.00   4.00
> 4  260.  173. 4.00   2.74
> 5  270.  138. 5.00   3.00
> 6  390.  262. 6.00   4.50
> 7  387.  275. 7.00   4.67
> 8  383.  287. 8.00   4.83
> ```

---

#### Visualize your results

You can check to make sure the points do indeed fall on the correct paths:

```
ggplot(path3d) + 
  geom_path(aes(t, x), color = "blue") +
  geom_path(aes(t, y), color = "red") +
  geom_path(aes(t, z*50), color = "orange") +
  geom_point(data = path3d_interp, aes(t, x), color = "blue") +
  geom_point(data = path3d_interp, aes(t, y), color = "red") +
  geom_point(data = path3d_interp, aes(t, z*50), color = "orange") +
  geom_text(data = path3d_interp, aes(t, z*50, label = round(z))) +
  labs(y = "x, y, z*50")
```

[image]

And see them in 3D:

```
plot_ly(path3d) %>% 
  add_paths(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z) %>% 
  add_markers(
    x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
    data = path3d_interp
    )  %>% 
  add_text(
    x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, text = ~round(z),
    data = path3d_interp
  )
```

[image]

---

## Updated again:

At the risk of being way too long-winded, I was reminded of the `uniroot` function, which does a pretty good job of this backsolving:

```
t_solutions <- map(1:8,
  ~uniroot(
    function(x) path3d_interp_funs$z(x) - .x, 
    interval = range(path3d$t)
  )
) %>% map_dbl("root")
```

> ```
>   1.833333 2.210526 2.473684 2.736842 4.333333 4.500000 4.666667 4.833333
> ```

However, you may notice that these solutions aren't the same as the ones from the previous method!

[image]

`uniroot` found solutions closer to the extremes of the interval, and not in the local region where the function changes direction. But that brings up the issue that there may be multiple `t` values for each of your desired `z` values. So a more robust solution:

```
root_finder <- function(f, zero, range, cuts) {

  endpts <- seq(range[1], range[2], length.out = cuts+1)

  range_list <- map2(endpts[-(cuts+1)], endpts[-1], c)

  safe_root <- possibly(uniroot, otherwise = NULL)
  f0 <- function(x) f(x) - zero

  map(range_list, ~safe_root(f0, interval = .x, maxiter = 100)$root) %>% 
    compact() %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    unique()

}
```

This function takes a function, a new desired "zero" for `uniroot` to solve for, a range of values to test the function over, and how many buckets to divide that range into. Then it tests for a solution in each bucket, and returns `NULL` if none is found. It then throws out the `NULL`s and removes any duplicates (if a solution is exactly at the border of a bucket, for example).

```
root_finder(path3d_interp_funs$z, zero = 4, range = range(path3d$t), cuts = 10)
```

> ```
> 2.736842 3.500000 4.166667
> ```

Then you can loop over all your desired `z` values to find the value(s) of `t` that satisfy it.

```
t_solutions <- map(
    1:8, 
    ~root_finder(path3d_interp_funs$z, zero = .x, range = range(path3d$t), cuts = 100)
  ) %>% unlist()
```

> ```
> 1.833333 2.210526 2.473684 4.000000 2.736842 3.500000 4.166667 3.000000 4.333333 4.500000 4.666667 4.833333
> ```

Then again passing these `t` values into each of the functions you created earlier, you can make a dataframe of all of them.

```
map(path3d_interp_funs, ~.x(t_solutions)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

> ```
>        x     y     z     t
>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
>  1  235   266.  1.    1.83
>  2  241.  242.  2.    2.21
>  3  251.  207.  3.    2.47
>  4  400   225   3     4   
>  5  260.  173.  4     2.74
>  6  335   182.  4     3.5 
>  7  397.  238.  4.    4.17
>  8  270   138   5     3   
>  9  393.  250.  5.00  4.33
> 10  390   262.  6     4.5 
> 11  387.  275   7.    4.67
> 12  383.  288.  8.00  4.83
> ```

Comment: This is a great answer @Brian, and great to learn about `approxfun`. Unfortunately, my area of application are particle paths which are not strictly monotonic in z. That is, the path can move up and down in z. I'm now updating the problem to reflect this.

Comment: You can interpolate all three of them against `t`, which I presume you have.

Comment: I do have `t`, which as you pointed out in your post, is the row order. Could you unpack what you mean by interpolating against `t`? I appreciate your help in this. Seems like you have ready insight into the problem.

Comment: @RichPauloo I've updated my answer again, with a faster and more robust method.

Comment: Thank you for the Herculean feat of coding @Brian. What I'm after is an interpolation between existing points that honors those points. I failed to make that clear in the OP, but all we need to do is `rbind.data.frame(path3d, df) %>% arrange(t)`, where `df` is the last df in your answer.